# Activar función, removerla y volverla a activar

Tags: javascript

Hice un scroll infinito (no tengo problema con eso, todo funciona bien) pero tengo una función llamada `addCardFilter()`, esta sirve para agregar productos al carrito de compras (tampoco tengo problema con eso, funciona perfectamente). Mi problema es que cuando voy haciendo scroll la función se llama varias veces, y cuando agrego un producto al carrito esta se agrega dependiendo de la paginación del scroll, es decir, si hice scroll y llamé dos veces a la petición Ajax, el producto se agrega dos veces.
Lo que quiero es que la función solo se llame una vez; ya lo hice sacando la función `addCardFilter()` fuera, pero si lo hago de esa manera, cuando hago scroll ya no se agrega al carrito porque tengo que llamar la función `addCardFilter()` cada vez que haga la petición Ajax.

Lo que quisiera es saber si existe una manera de llamar la función `addCardFilter()`, hacer el scroll, hacer la petición ajax, después quitarla y llamarla otra vez, pero que se ejecute solo una vez al ir haciendo scroll.

```
let pagina = 0;
let ultimoProducto;
cargarProductos(pagina);

let observador = new IntersectionObserver((entradas, observador) => {
  entradas.forEach(entrada => {
    if (entrada.isIntersecting) {
      pagina++;
      cargarProductos(pagina);
    }
  })
}, {
  rootMargin: '0px  0px 200px 0px',
  threshold: 1.0
})
```

````
  var totalRecord = pagina;
  var totalData = $("#totalRecords").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url + '/Tienda/fil',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { totalRecord: totalRecord },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#results").append(data.products);
      if (totalRecord <= totalData) {
        if (ultimoProducto) {
          observador.unobserve(ultimoProducto);
        }
        let productosEnPantalla = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedor .producto');
        ultimoProducto = productosEnPantalla[productosEnPantalla.length - 1];
        observador.observe(ultimoProducto);
        addCartFilter();
      }
      totalRecord++;
    }
  });
}```
````